# Get a list of friends of a friend on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've recently started looking into the Facebook API and am trying to work out how to retrieve the list of friends of another user (in this case the user is someone I'm friends with).

So far I've only worked out how to find out the friends of a person who I am also friends with. However the Friends Wheel application can do it as you can generate a wheel base on one of your friends, so I'm guessing it is possible.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You Can only access friends list of logged in user(i.e, your friend list) or the logged             in user's friends that are users of your app. i.e, You can access friends friend list only if your friends are the users of your app.

Comment: Any idea why this is, because as a logged in user I can see it, they are limiting the app's permissions on the account and I don't know a programmatic way to see what I see when I am logged in.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if two of your friends are friends using `friends.are_friends`.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've got a valid access token for a user, you can query the Graph API with said token and query the "**friends**" connection of the user object (*/me/friends*). So if your user ID is "123":

https://graph.facebook.com/123/friends?access_token=USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN

You can also use /me to reference the current user:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN

Without a valid access token, you cannot query information about users and access to friends of friends is determined by each user. For example, I cannot see some of my friend's friends:

> Can't lookup all friends of (ID). Can only lookup for the logged in
>   user (ID), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate
>   permission.

...but for some of my other friends, I can. There's probably a permission or flag you can check to see if they allow access, but I'm not currently seeing it.

Comment: The friends whose friends you can access have also authorised your app

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out.

1) The best you can do is find mutual friends
2) Try using the v1.0 of the Facebook Graph API. v2.0 doesn't have `/mutualfriends`.
3) Since I was only interested in my own social network, I grabbed the access token from the graph explorer and wrote a python script to download my whole social network. The code is [on github](https://github.com/ccorcos/python-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible to get List of Friends of a friend but only condition is that friend should be user of that application.

Suppose there is an application "APP" used by "A" then the APP can get his friends List , now you want friends List of "B" who is friend of "A" , it will be possible only if "B" also uses the "APP"

Answer (score 0):

Facebook are in the process of deprecating the REST API, and have added equivalent support to the Graph API for this method. You can use Graph API - User object and Get /User_id1/friends/User_id2 to check if User_id1 is friends with User_id2 .