# getting list of friends from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, socialauth, facebook-friends

Facebook API does not provide friends list of people using our fb app, according to their developer faq page. But still, websites like [nimble](http://www.nimble.com) and the live example of [socialauth](https://labs.3pillarglobal.com/socialauthdemo/importContacts.do) are able to get the names of people on our friend list, even those who do not use their app. Please, can any one help me with how this work?

The read_friendlist permission gives only name of lists like 'close friends', 'aquaintance' etc. the user_friends permission gives only the list of people in our friendlist who use our app.
What all api permssions do we need to get the full friend list?

I am trying to make an address book by importing contacts from google, facebook etc. using socialauth. Had success with google.

Comment: Can be duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897749/get-a-list-of-my-friends-friends)..?

Comment: @ekostadinov, could be. but isn't this one more specific? I'd like to know how [nimble](https://www.nimble.com) and [socialauth live example](http://labs.3pillarglobal.com/socialauthdemo/importContacts.do) exported my facebook contacts as facebook api has stopped providing that service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those websites are probably using older Apps with v1.0 - it will stop working for them after end of April 2015. You can only use v1.0 with an App created before end of April 2014.

Comment: is there any workaround for getting friends list with the new api?

Comment: there is invitable_friends and taggable_friends, but those are for inviting users and tagging users only. so no, for your case there is no workaround, i am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

All 'friends_*' permissions have been removed from new version 2.1 
You can use 'user_friends'

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

For fetching app users user 'me/friends'

For more friends use 'me/taggable_friends' . 
Remember it will still not return whole friends.

In new facebook api version there is no way to fetch whole friend list at one time