# Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently developing a facebook application using a Facebook PHP SDK I could access my profile

```
$request = new   FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me');
        $profile = $request->execute()->getGraphObject('Facebook\GraphUser');
        echo $profile->getId();
```

and now I'm trying to get Id of all my friends my code is

permission

```
echo ' <a href="'. $helper->getReRequestUrl(['user_friends']).'">Se connecter avec facebook</a>';
```

my code to get friends id list

```
$request = new   FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/'.$id.'/friends');
```

but the result give me juste number of friends

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like you're out of luck, as the updated Graph API doesn't allow for getting a whole list of friends.

See this question and comments for more information:
[getting list of friends from facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113532/getting-list-of-friends-from-facebook)

Comment: Further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0?rq=1