# Can a Facebook app access a user's friends' friend lists,?

Tags: facebook

On the one hand, if his friends haven't signed in we may not know who all of their friends are. On the other hand, friend lists are public for most
people. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of Friends of a Friend on facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330123/get-a-list-of-friends-of-a-friend-on-facebook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging, this is not possible.  Apps can't get complete lists of friends for users who have not used those apps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**read_friendlists**

Provides access to any friend lists the user created. All user's friends are provided as part of basic data, this extended permission grants access to the lists of friends a user has created, and should only be requested if your application utilizes lists of friends.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Shahid.  I know an app can access users friend lists.  But I'm wondering if an app can also access users' friends' friend lists (so if I'm using the app and you're my friend, the app can see who your friends are).  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: have you tried $friends = $facebook->api('/FRIEND_ID_HERE/friends/');  ... i have not tried but it should work

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this works.  Facebook won't return friends of a friend who hasn't used the app.