# Facebook -> view friends of a friend

Tags: c#, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a list of Friends of a Friend on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330123/get-a-list-of-friends-of-a-friend-on-facebook)

I'd like to do a research about my school social network. I will map this network with the help of facebook. It would be important to see the friends of my friends (their ID would be enough). With the Graph api i can only list my friends. When i try to find my friends's friends i get an error: "Unsupported operation, FacebookApiException, code 100". I read this API doesn't support this operation anymore. I thought I could solve this problem by making a desktop facebook client-like application, but i couldn't find anything about logging in with my own username and password with the c# API. There is the Facebook Developer Toolkit, but it seems outdated. Would it worth a try or do you any solution for my problem?

ps.: of course everything is ok with the application and user token

Comment: I've already seen this topic, but they said that there is no solution. If it can't be then done how do Facebook clients work?

Comment: It can’t be done with what the API offers, period. And what do you mean by “Facebook clients”?

Comment: A desktop or mobile application that can be used instead of www.facebook.com

Comment: Per the answer i linked, and many other duplicates, this is NOT possible via the API unless the friend also uses your app

Comment: But what if I want to code an application in c# like the "Facebook" for android?

Comment: I took look at the Facebook mobile application and saw that is written by the Facbook company itself. Hasn't anybody tryed to decompile it to know how can it display your friends' friends?